# How to make a column of python DataFrame editable in Zeppelin Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-zeppelin

I have an aggregated pandas DataFrame (10-20 rows) in Zeppelin Notebook (python interpreter) with a column **score** and another column **factor**.

I want to create a new column, **adjustable score** which would be score*factor.

To make this happen I'm trying to create the factor column editable.

Comment: What kind of dataframes? Pandas? Spark? I cannot really understand what is your problem.

Comment: Zeppelin doesn't offer editable HTML tables for dataframes. Please show your code

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I should have mentioned, that it is a pandas Dataframe

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the update

Comment: You can do `df['new_column'] = data`, in code, though

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the response, however i was looking for something similar to editable tables in HTML, or bokeh.models.widgets.tables editable tables.  however I don't know how to save the edited (updated) table from bokeh back to pandas df

Comment: Yeah, I don't think zeppelin does two way data binding like that without some custom Angular JS code